# Procedure to restrict multiple access to a particular method in Java EE

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, synchronization, resultset

I wanted to know the procedure to restrict multiple access to a particular method in JAVA.
If same method is called parallel by many machines(which will return a result set), I wanted the second method call to wait till the first method call completes its process fully.
Is there any feature to in java to achieve this functionality.

I am working on a Java EE application which will 
open a excel file from DB,
it process the variables inside it with the user values,
and it will update tat report in DB and download the updated copy to the user.

Here when multiple person opens the file and process process the data at the same time it will result an error.
Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Make the method `synchronized`?

Comment: You have to synchronize the method with the "synchronized" keyword. Go through basics of Java Threads

Comment: Yes i have tried using both 
by using "synchronize" keyword before method and by using "synchronize (this){}"
But no use the issue exist still.

Answer (score 1):

Using `synchronized` won't work if you want to restrict callers in different JVMs, because there's no single lock they can all use. Each caller is using a lock local to its own instance of the application. So Java doesn't have a way to do this for you.

The thing that everyone is sharing is the row in the database, and that's what you should be locking on. Assuming your Excel file is in a blob in the database, and assuming everything you do with the excel file can be done within one transaction, then you can use database transactions and exclusive locking to restrict access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

See here for an explanation of [Synchronized Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html). This will block all callers but one and let them in sequentially.